# Detect IMPORTXML() Loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to detect "Loading..." error for `=IMPORTXML()`?
I would like to return different value when the external URL is still loading and different for the real error, so `=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(...))` doesn't really do the work.
Preferably without scripting.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Well, it's really simple. When I try to get any URL using formula `=IMPORTXML()` there is a `Loading...` error until the URL is read and after the full execution there is a desired data from URL or other error. I would like to recognize `Loading...` from another errors somehow.

Comment: This isn't a return value as asked, but you can sort to group "Loading..." results, in case that's helpful for later processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the =IFNA() function instead of IFERROR

Usually, #N/A errors are encountered as a result of page detection. If this is what you mean by saying "other error", "realy error", you can indirectly detect the "Loading..." error using the above formula.

Comment: "Loading ..." is not detected with IFNA(). See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67195560/4752223