# Run googlefinance only once per hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet in which I am keeping an eye on a few hundred stocks. In one of the columns, I am using a `googlefinance` call to retrieve the price of these stocks:

```
=googlefinance(A1,"price")
```

I regularly make changes to the sheet: I cut and paste rows to reorder the stocks, I add stocks, or delete them. The problem with this is that on each change in the rows, the `googlefinance` function is run again for all hundreds of stocks. After 3 or 4 times the price information isn't loading anymore and I have to refresh the browser tab and/or have to wait until I am below the number of allowed calls per day again.

I do not need the price to change contantly. I would be more than happy if the price is retrieved only, say, once per hour.

Question: how can I have the 'googlefinance' function in column B of my Sheet only run once per hour instead of on every change of the Sheet?

Comment: have you tried the last parameter (`interval`) to specify when to retrieve data ? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281. I've never tried but it seems to be made for your case.

Comment: This is returning a daily of weekly quote for a defined daterange. It does not run the formula only "daily" or "weekly". So for instance `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31), "DAILY")` returns 193 quotations.

Comment: I use GOOGLEFINANCE to get my stock quotes and what I do is have a script that goes down a list of symbols, put a formula in a cell `=GOOGLEFINANCE("IBM","price",DATE,DATE,"DAILY")` copy the results to another sheet, run the next symbol, copy, etc. etc. etc. I run it all from a Custom Menu Item.  That way there is really only the last GOOGLEFINANCE formula in my spreadsheet.  And I don't care about that data, I've copied what I want to another sheet.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514985/how-to-make-google-sheet-formula-just-calculate-once) answer your question?